# how to display the items in each week lits?

Tags: php, laravel

How to show this item in week 1 and week 2 like that now it's coming together needs to be displayed in a separate tab under week 1 only show week food, week 2 food under show only under week 2 menu. How to show this item in week 1 and week 2 like that now it's coming together needs to be displayed in a separate tab under week 1 only show week food, week 2 food under show only under week 2 menu.

```
    <table id="user-list-table" class="table table-striped" role="grid" data-toggle="data-table" style="font-size: 13px;">
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Breakfast</th>
                <th>Lunch</th>
                <th>Snacks</th>
                <th>Dinner</th>
            </tr>
    
        @php
        $i = 0;
        $week = 1;
        $fromm = new DateTime($dt);
        $firstDayName = strtolower($fromm->format('l'));
        $dayName = strtolower($fromm->format('l'));
        @endphp
    
        @for ($i = 0; $i < $diff; $i++) @php $menuCategoryCG0001=array_filter($mnu_arr, function ($ma) { return $ma['category_code']=='CG0001' ; }); $menuCategoryCG0002=array_filter($mnu_arr, function ($ma) { return $ma['category_code']=='CG0002' ; }); $menuCategoryCG0003=array_filter($mnu_arr, function ($ma) { return $ma['category_code']=='CG0003' ; }); $menuCategoryCG0004=array_filter($mnu_arr, function ($ma) { return $ma['category_code']=='CG0004' ; }); @endphp <tr style="height: 50px">
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $custom_plan_id }}" name="customplanid">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $diff }}" name="numdays">
                <input type="hidden" id="mdbf-{{ $i }}">
                <input type="text" name="date-{{ $i }}" value="{{ $dt }}" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded iq-col-masonry-block"><br><br>
                
                <input type="text"  value="Week-{{   $week  }}" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded iq-col-masonry-block">
                
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach ($menuCategoryCG0001 as $ma)
                @if($ma['day'] == $dayName && $ma['week'] == $week)
                <div id="button" href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded iq-col-masonry-block">
                    <img src="{{ asset('menuimages/' . $ma['image']) }}" width="81px"><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ $ma['category_code'] . '-' . $i }}[]" value="{{ $ma['id'] }}" class="check">
                    <p style="font-size: 10px;">{{ $ma['name'] }}</p>
                </div><br><br>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach ($menuCategoryCG0002 as $ma)
                @if($ma['day'] == $dayName  && $ma['week'] == $week)
                <div id="button" href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded iq-col-masonry-block">
                    <img src="{{ asset('menuimages/' . $ma['image']) }}" width="81px"><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ $ma['category_code'] . '-' . $i }}[]" value="{{ $ma['id'] }}" class="check">
                    <p style="font-size: 10px;">{{ $ma['name'] }} <br><br>Protein/Carb : {{ $lunchp_c }}</p>
                </div><br><br>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach ($menuCategoryCG0003 as $ma)
                @if($ma['day'] == $dayName  && $ma['week'] == $week)
                <div id="button" href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded iq-col-masonry-block">
                    <img src="{{ asset('menuimages/' . $ma['image']) }}" width="81px"><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ $ma['category_code'] . '-' . $i }}[]" value="{{ $ma['id'] }}" class="check">
                    <p style="font-size: 10px;">{{ $ma['name'] }}</p>
                </div><br><br>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach ($menuCategoryCG0004 as $ma)
                @if($ma['day'] == $dayName  && $ma['week'] == $week)
                <div id="button" href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded iq-col-masonry-block">
                    <img src="{{ asset('menuimages/' . $ma['image']) }}" width="81px"><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ $ma['category_code'] . '-' . $i }}[]" value="{{ $ma['id'] }}" class="check">
                    <p style="font-size: 10px;">{{ $ma['name'] }} <br><br>Protein/Carb : {{ $dinnerp_c }}</p>
                </div><br><br>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </td>
            </tr>
            @php
            $dt = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dt . ' + 1 days'));
            $day = new DateTime($dt);
            $day = $day->format('l');
            if ($day == 'Friday') {
            $dt = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dt . ' + 1 days'));
            }
            $fromm = new DateTime($dt);
            $dayName = strtolower($fromm->format('l'));
            if($firstDayName === $dayName){
                $week++;
            }
            if($week == 3){
                $week = 1;
            }
            if($week == 4){
                $week = 2;
            }
            @endphp
            @endfor
    </table>
```

Comment: fyi, `id`s must be unique, you have multiple `id="button"` - that's invalid. `<div>` doesn't take a `href` attribute. `width` attribute doesn't take units

Comment: @brombeer  how i can change this

Comment: What is intent of `href="#"`? That anchor doesnt have a name so wouldnt scroll anywhere. Could add an `<a>` inside the div. Change `id` to `class` or append an incrementing value to the name so it is unique. `width` can be change with `style` attribute like you have elsewhere, `style="width: 81px;"`.